# ReadDirectoryChangesW never calls the callback

Tags: c++, winapi

I have some code, that never calls the callback, even if I copy, change or delete a file in `C:\Temp`. What am I doing wrong?
It seems to be stuck at `WaitForSingleObject()` and never calls `DirectoryChangeCallback` at all.

The program should be easy to understand and is complete, so it should run when you try it.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")

#include <string>

VOID CALLBACK DirectoryChangeCallback(DWORD dwErrorCode, DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped) {
    ASSERT(FALSE); // program never comes here
}


int main() {
    std::wstring path = L"C:\\Temp";

    // Set up a directory change notification
    HANDLE hDirectory = CreateFileW(path.c_str()
                                    , GENERIC_READ
                                    , FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE
                                    , NULL
                                    , OPEN_EXISTING
                                    , FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED
                                    , NULL);
    if(hDirectory == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        // Handle error
        return 1;
    }

    BYTE buffer[4096];  // Buffer to receive notification information
    DWORD dwBytesReturned;
    OVERLAPPED overlapped= {};
    overlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if(overlapped.hEvent == NULL) {
        // Handle error
        CloseHandle(hDirectory);
        return 1;
    }

    // Start monitoring for changes
    DWORD dwNotifyFilter = FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME  | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE /*FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY| FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES*/;
    if(!ReadDirectoryChangesW(hDirectory, buffer, sizeof(buffer), TRUE/*subtree*/, dwNotifyFilter, NULL, &overlapped, DirectoryChangeCallback)) {
        if(GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
            // Handle error
            CloseHandle(overlapped.hEvent);
            CloseHandle(hDirectory);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Wait for changes and process notifications in the callback function
    wprintf(L"Wait for single object\n");
    DWORD dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(overlapped.hEvent, INFINITE); // *** STUCK HERE ***
    wprintf(L"result %d\n", int(dwWaitResult));


    // Clean up resources
    CloseHandle(overlapped.hEvent);
    CloseHandle(hDirectory);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As per the docs, your thread needs to be in an alertable wait state for the callback to be triggered. `WaitForSingleObject` isn't good enough, you need to use `WaitForSingleObjectEx` with the `fAlertable` parameter set to `TRUE`.

Comment: this code have no sense, because you from one side want asynchronous notifications, and from another - use synchronous pattern, when simply wait in place, after api call. more - event notfication and apc notification at once - have no sense. select only one. the best - bind file to iocp and notwait in place

Comment: The WaitForSingleObjectEx did the trick. Now, how can I get the filename of the file that changed?

Comment: this not tric - code wrong anyway. for what you use hEvent if you want use APC ? also `buffer` must be DWORD-aligned ( more exactly - same align as `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` ). in practice, such stack defined usually will be, but this is mistake how you declared it. name in FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION

Comment: @KungPhoo the file names are stored in the `buffer` that you give to `ReadDirectoryChangesW()`. The `buffer` will receive 1 or more [`FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-file_notify_information) structs, one for each event.

Answer (score -1):

As @RbMm said, your usage of *CreateFileW* doesn't match the usage of *ReadDirectoryChangesW*.
Also there are three asynchronous ways mentioned in [ReadDirectoryChangesW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw#remarks) function but none of them is same as the code.

> - Using the GetOverlappedResult function. To receive notification    through GetOverlappedResult, do not specify a completion routine in
>   the lpCompletionRoutine parameter. Be sure to set the hEvent member
>   of the OVERLAPPED structure to a unique event.
> - Using the GetQueuedCompletionStatus function. To receive notification    through GetQueuedCompletionStatus, do not specify a
>   completion    routine in lpCompletionRoutine. Associate the directory
>   handle    hDirectory with a completion port by calling the
>   CreateIoCompletionPort function.
> - Using a completion routine. To receive notification through a    completion routine, do not associate the directory with a completion
>   port. Specify a completion routine in lpCompletionRoutine. This
>   routine is called whenever the operation has been completed or
>   canceled while the thread is in an alertable wait state. The hEvent
>   member of the OVERLAPPED structure is not used by the system, so you
>   can use it yourself.

asynchronous sample: [CloudMirror](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/7cbd99ac1d2b4a0beffbaba29ea63d024ceff700/Samples/CloudMirror/CloudMirror/DirectoryWatcher.cpp#L24)
synchronous sample: [fileserviceservice](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/7cbd99ac1d2b4a0beffbaba29ea63d024ceff700/Samples/Win7Samples/web/wsdapi/fileservice/fileserviceservice/Service.cpp#L726)

Comment: Hello @KungPhoo, Have you checked my answer?